# Why React Component is being invoked multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to create a simple ToDo app in react native.
Everything works almost fine, but I am seeing a issue where a component is being called multiple times post navigation.
I am using 'react-native-router-flux' for routing.

Here is the Router config

```
export default RouterComponent = ()=>{
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="main">
         <Scene key="taskList" component={TaskList} title='Task List' initialrenderBackButton={()=>null}></Scene>
         <Scene key="task" component={TaskList} title='Task'></Scene>
         <Scene key="createTask" component={CreateTask} title='Create A Task'></Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
   );
}
```

In the component 'CreateTask' I am navigating back to the component 'TaskList' which basically shows a list of tasks.

```
onTaskSubmit() {
  Actions.taskList({init:false});
}
```

As you can see, while calling the 'Actions' I am passing 'init' props as 'false'.

In the component 'TaskList', here is an excerpt from the render method -

```
render() {    
   console.log(this.props.init);
}
```

The console.log shows 'false' as I expect, but, somehow its getting called again, and its showing a value 'true'.

What am I missing here?

Please let me know if I can provide further information.

Comment: It would be great if provided [snack](http://snack.expo.io) example with minimal code!